# Android PagerTabStrip - Update TextView in Fragment from another Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

How can I update TextView in one of the tabs at any action on the other tab? I tried with the help of the static methods. Here's my non-working code:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.tabs.example;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager            mViewPager;
    int                  pageCount = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageCount);

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragment;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new Fragment2();
                    break;
                default:
                    fragment  = null;
                    break;
            }
            return fragment;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return pageCount;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment1:**

```
package com.tabs.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.tabs.example.Fragment2;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText("Fragment 1");

        Fragment2.update("From Fragment 1 with Love");

        return root;

    }

}
```

**Fragment2:**

```
package com.tabs.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public static TextView tv1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

        tv1 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv1.setText("Fragment 2");

        return root;

    }

    public static void update(String text) {
        tv1.setText(text);
    }
}
```

How can I do it?
Thanks.